# Oracle 21c unified_audit_trail SQL_TEXT

Tags: database, oracle, oracle21c

I am having trouble outputting SQL_TEXT, one of the columns in unified_audit_trail in Oracle 21c. SQL_TEXT has a data type of CLOB, but it does not show all the SQL, only 80 total characters including spaces (maximum 60 characters per line).

1. Executed SQL

```
SELECT Posts.title, MAX(Comments.created_at) AS latest_comment_date
FROM Posts
LEFT JOIN Comments ON Posts.postID = Comments.postID
GROUP BY Posts.title
ORDER BY latest_comment_date DESC;
```

1-result) UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL

```
SELECT Posts.title, MAX(Comments.created_at) AS latest_comme
nt_date
FROM Posts
L

SELECT Posts.title, MAX(Comments.created_at) AS latest_comme
nt_date
FROM Posts
L
```

2. Executed SQL

```
SELECT Posts.title, Users.username AS post_author, Comments.userID AS comment_author
FROM Posts
JOIN Users ON Posts.userID = Users.userID
JOIN Comments ON Posts.postID = Comments.postID
WHERE Posts.userID != Comments.userID;
```

2-result)UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL

```
SELECT Posts.title, Users.username AS post_author, Comments.
userID AS comment_au

SELECT Posts.title, Users.username AS post_author, Comments.
userID AS comment_au

SELECT Posts.title, Users.username AS post_author, Comments.
userID AS comment_au
```

How can I get the full query?
Note: I was able to see the entire SQL in DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL(SQL_TEXT) without any problems.

Comment: It's probably how your client software is configured to handle LOBs. Check your program's configuration and find the setting that says how much of a LOB to preview, or find out how to open up the LOB in a separate window that fetches the full content. The reason why it's different with `dba_audit_trail` is because there it's an `nvarchar2(2000 char)` snippet, not a LOB.